# Array Not Updating in ViewModel Despite Subscription

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, core-data, combine

I'm facing an issue in my iOS app's architecture involving CoreData, the HistoryCallDataService class, and the HistoryViewModel. I'm hoping someone can help shed light on the problem I'm encountering.

Problem Description:

I'm working with CoreData and have an array that I'm managing through the HistoryCallDataService class.

```
class HistoryCallDataService {

private let container: NSPersistentContainer
private let containerName = "CallHistoryData"
private let entityName = "HistoryData"

@Published var savedEntities: [HistoryData] = []

init() {
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: containerName)
    container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("## Error loading Core data :\(error)")
        }
        self.getHistoryData()
    }
}

private func getHistoryData(){
    let request = NSFetchRequest<HistoryData>(entityName: entityName)
    
    do {
        savedEntities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch let error {
        print("## Error fetch: \(error)")
    }
}

 func add(firstName: String, lastName: String, telephone: String, callHidden: Bool) {
    let entity = HistoryData(context: container.viewContext)
    
    let date = Date()
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let timeString = df.string(from: date)
    
    entity.firstName = firstName
    entity.lastName = lastName
    entity.telephone = telephone
    entity.time = timeString
    entity.callHidden = callHidden
    appleChanges()
}

   private func save(){
    do {
        try container.viewContext.save()
    } catch let error {
        print("## Error saving to core data \(error)")
    }
}

    private func appleChanges(){
    save()
    getHistoryData()
}
```

I'm observing changes in the savedEntities property of the HistoryCallDataService class using the historyDataService.$savedEntities publisher. When the app starts, the array is updated correctly. However, if I add new content, the savedEntities array updates, but the historyArray in the HistoryViewModel does not reflect these changes.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class HistoryViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var searchText:String = ""
@Published var historyArray: [HistoryData] = []

private let historyDataService = HistoryCallDataService()

private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

var selectedContact: HistoryData? = nil

@Published var filteredContacts: [HistoryData] = []

init(){
    addSubscribers()
}

func addSubscribers(){
    historyDataService.$savedEntities

        .debounce(for: 1.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { [weak self] (returnData) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.historyArray = returnData
            self.updateFilteredContacts()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

func updateFilteredContacts() {
    
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredContacts = historyArray
    } else {
        filteredContacts = historyArray.filter { contact in
            contact.firstName?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) ?? false ||
            contact.lastName?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) ?? false ||
            contact.telephone?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) ?? false
        }
    }
}
```

The view:

```
    private var contactList: some View{
    
    List{
        ForEach(vm.filteredContacts) { item in
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("\(item.firstName ?? "N/A") \(item.lastName ?? "N/A" )")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("\(item.telephone ?? "N/A")")
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .padding(.top,1)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                    Text("\(item.time ?? "N/A")")
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                    Text("\(item.callHidden ? "Hidden" : "Normally ")")
                        .foregroundColor(item.callHidden ? Color.theme.red : Color.theme.black)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.top,1)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                vm.selectedContact = item
                showingCallAlert.toggle()
            }
            .listRowBackground(vm.selectedContact?.telephone == item.telephone && showingCallAlert ? Color.theme.gray : nil)
        }
        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
            for index in indexSet {
                let contactToDelete = vm.filteredContacts[index]
                vm.delete(entity: contactToDelete)
            }
        })
    }
    .onChange(of:
                vm.searchText) { _ in
        vm.updateFilteredContacts()
    }
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                    if newPhase == .active {
                        print("Active")
                        vm.updateFilteredContacts()
                    }
                }
                .lineLimit(1)
                .listStyle(.plain)
}
```

If anyone has encountered a similar situation or has insights into what might be causing this behavior, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Lot of potential issues here, HistoryCallDataService has a `Published` property but doesn’t conform to ObservableObject although it shouldn’t work anyway since `Published` only works between a class conforming to ObservableObject and a View. Another issue is that you create a new instance of HistoryCallDataService inside your view model even though it has a property for a persistence container, this could mean that you use different containers/stores in different parts of your app.

Comment: what i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Withou a minimal reproducible example it is impossible to help. You could be dealing with multiple disconnected instances of objects. Also, just staying the obvious trying to recreate all the logic that FetchRequest provides is unnecessary and a waste of resources.

Comment: When I delete content the array is updated, only when I add to the array it does not work. the savedEntities get the new content, but the historyArray the not updated! even i call updateFilteredContacts() again.

Comment: CoreData itself conforms to the `ObservableObject` protocol, but I suspect what is happening in the`HistoryCallDataService` that you are not showing us is you are nesting your CoreData entity into another class that conforms to `ObservableObject`, and then are trying to subscribe through that. The issue you may be having is that the `HistoryCallDataService` is not updating when CoreData changes. Please show the `HistoryCallDataService` and preferably a a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Usually if you remove the legacy custom view model object and use the built-in `@FetchRequest` view model it works better.